# How do I use a playground to clone and modify demos from a github repo?

Tags: javascript, github

I have a JavaScript library with LOTS of demos. And I'm going to teach a group of students on how to use it next summer.

I want the students to be able to edit & run the demos in the browser without downloading the repo to their computers.

This is to avoid having them to learn how to use the desktop with all the subtleties of a dev server, git & github, node, npm, bundling, OS differences and so on. The students are noobies and I need to keep it simple.

How can I use a playground (codepen, jsben, jsfiddle, etc) to edit & run the demos?

The repo [is here](https://code.agentscript.org/), and the typical demo directory would be [like this](https://code.agentscript.org/views2/).